# SQL tracker to log changes in table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table called `table`:

```
id    int(11)      AI    PK
name  varchar(255)
```

I store logs in `table_log`

```
id     int(11)    AI    PK
action enum('insert', 'update', 'delete')
name   varchar(255)
ts     timestamp  current_timestam
```

**Goal**: I want to create triggers to store logs into `table_log`

Here are TRIGGERS:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `table_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `table`
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
      INSERT INTO `table_log` (id, action, name, ts)
      VALUES(NEW.id, 'insert', NEW.name, NOW());
    END;

CREATE TRIGGER `table_update` AFTER INSERT ON `table`
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
      INSERT INTO table_log (id, action, name, ts)
      VALUES(NEW.id, 'update', NEW.name, NOW());
    END;

CREATE TRIGGER `table_delete` AFTER INSERT ON `table`
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
      INSERT INTO `table_log` (id, action, name, ts)
      VALUES(OLD.id, 'delete', OLD.name, NOW());
    END;
```

I tried to create trigger but there is error in syntax:

**Error**

```
SQL query:

CREATE TRIGGER `table_insert` AFTER INSERT ON  `table` 
FOR EACH
ROW 
BEGIN 
INSERT INTO  `table_log` ( id, 
ACTION , name, ts ) 
VALUES (

NEW.id,  'insert', NEW.name, NOW( )
);

MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5
```

Comment: Don't use `table` as table name!! It is also a reserved word and you need to escape it with backticks. But don't use it. What does table say about a table - nothing.

Comment: Yes I noticed that. I put word table into brackets like ` table` `

Comment: As I said - it would be better to use a different name instead of escaping with backticks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't set another delimiter than `;`, then the statement will end at the first `;` and your trigger definition will be incomplete. You need to tell *MySQL* that the statement should end at the delimiter you defined. After that you can set the delimiter back with `delimiter ;`

```
delimiter |
CREATE TRIGGER `table_insert` AFTER INSERT ON  `table` 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
  INSERT INTO  `table_log` ( id, ACTION , name, ts ) 
  VALUES (NEW.id,  'insert', NEW.name, NOW( ));
END
|
delimiter ;
```

## And don't use TABLE as a table name! Use a more descriptive name.

Comment: I was using `table` as table name for EXAMPLE, to simplify my problem to basic idea.